# Add checkbox to wordpress woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have `woocommerce` store in my `wordperss` site.
What I want is I want to add checkbox box to my product page in front side.

[image]

How can I do this??

Need Your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the checkbox to do?

Comment: There will be a option that "Do you want printing for this product?".If user will check that checkbox and click on add to cart button then in cart page I should have allow printing cost to be added in product.To have more idea about this see this site: http://www.myshadicards.com/weddingcards.asp?id=37

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way but I guess you could something along the lines of this..

Add the checkbox in `single-product\add-to-cart\simple.php` inside the `form` and then `add_action('init', 'check_for_checkbox_value_here');` and inside the init hook you can store that checkbox value in the session and then check on checkout page for that session value.

Then on action `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` you can save that value in the database for future reference or any backend functionalities you may be having.

Hope that helps!